# Both mouse and keyboard can use at once time in monkeyrunner?

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner

Can we perform mouseclick event and keyboard press event at once testing time in monkeyrunner?
If yes then how? Please tell me.

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of this question. There is no way to use the mouseclick in Monkeyrunner. We can get only keyboard press event in the Monkeyrunner.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use MonkeyRunner.DOWN for both actions then do something like MonkeyRunner.sleep(.25) and use MonkeyRunner.UP for those same actions.

You will need to pick one of the events to happen first, however both should happen fast enough that it won't matter.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I do it by another way.